# como obtener una función que retorne en una lista de cuantas monedas son necesarias para devolverle dicho valor

Tags: python, python-3.x, base-de-datos, script, programación-funcional

el cual ya llevo adelantado pero no sé cómo terminarlo. Tengo un monto entre 1 y 99 centavos de Dolar, debo escribir un metodo que retorne en una lista de cuantas monedas son necesarias para devolverle a alguien dicho valor, si únicamente se cuenta con monedas de 1, 10 y 25 centavos . La lista debe entregarse de la siguiente manera:

La función recibirá una cantidad entre 1 y 99 centavos y deberá devolver una lista con tres números [n1, n10, n25], especificando cuántas monedas de 1, 10 y 25 céntimos se necesitan para obtener el amonut dado. Solo tenemos monedas de 1, 10 y 25 céntimos. No existen otros tipos de monedas.

Si la cantidad entregada es menor de 1 o mayor de 99 debe regresar None.

Mi ejemplo va así, pero no sé si lo llevo bien y tampoco sé cómo debo continuarlo para que escoja la combinación de monedas.

```
def change_money(n):
  r=[1,10,25]
  new=[]
  for i in r:
    sum(i)
    new.append[n//i]
``
Agradezco de ante mano su ayuda.
```

Comment: No vas bien. Lo que tienes que hacer es dividir por 25 (usando división entera) para saber cuántas monedas de 25 necesitas. Después tomas el resto y divides por 10 (división entera) para saber cuántas de 10. Finalmente el resto de esta última división será el número de monedas de 1. Con estos resultados armas la lista que debes retornar. No te doy el código de la respuesta para forzarte a pensar sobre ello e intentarlo tú misma. Si te atascas, edita la pregunta para poner lo que llevas hecho y dónde te falla.

Comment: Podrías trabajar todo en céntimos, 100 = 1 moneda de 1$. La clave está en realizar la matemática primero, con esa lógica definida como dice el maestro @abulafia ya tendrías gran avance. Lo bueno de tu escenario: estás libre de restricciones de la cantidad de monedas. Saludos

Comment: Si lo quieres hacer con un bucle como el que tienes planteado, debes recorrer el array `r` "al revés" (usa `reversed()`), para comenzar por la moneda mayor. En cada iteración añades a tu array `new` el resultado de la división entera de `n` entre la moneda que toque, y actualizas `n` para que sea el resto de esa división.

Comment: Existe un algoritmo para saber la menor cantidad de monedas, una vez lo hice, y no estas ni cerca de lograr tu objetivo, solo usa las recomendaciones de @abulafia bastara para lograr lo que quieres

Comment: Lo que dice el señor abulafia es: si n = 55,

cuando creo la lista new[] es para que allí vayan la división entera de n que es 55// i que i es 25,10 y 1 respectivamente. O si no es de manera individual sino lo que quede? de cada uno ? es decir primero sería 55//25 y lo que quede lo divido en 10 y en 1 sucesivamente?

Comment: @Graciela. Efectivamente. Empiezas dividiendo entre 25, lo que te da de cociente 2 y de resto 5. El cociente es la cantidad de monedas de 25, el resto es lo que queda para proseguir con el algoritmo. A eso que queda le aplicas el mismo tratamiento pero dividiendo entre 10 (en este caso sale cociente 0 y resto 5). Finalmente divides entre 1 (aunque este paso realmente puede ahorrarse). El resultado final sería [2, 0 , 5], que son los cocientes obtenidos en cada uno de los pasos.

Comment: Ahh ya ya te estiendo la lógica del problema. Estoy haciendo mi función y voy  
```def change_money(n):
    r=[0,0,0]
    r[0]=1
    r[1]=10
    r=[2]=25
    for i in r:
      n//r[i]
    #if n>99 or n<1: use return None
```  Pero no sé como decirle que empiece desde el r[2] que es el último elemento de r de manera que vaya por cada uno.

Comment: `for i in reversed(r)`. Y de todas formas te falta ir metiendo en la lista de resultados los cocientes que vayas obteniendo, y cambiando `n` en cada iteración para que sea el resto de la división (`n%i`). El chequeo de que `n` esté entre 1 y 99 debes hacerlo al inicio de la función, para retornar sin hacer nada si no es así.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Saludos te envió código en python

[image: Imagen de código funcionando]

Comment: Bienvenido. Todo lo que puedas mostrar como texto debe ir como texto. Luego si querés puedes agregar imágenes que ayuden a explicar la pregunta o respuesta.

Comment: Bienvenido, revisa [answer], saludos.